# Is it possible to draw charts with json data?

Tags: json, charts, google-visualization

Is there any good article that gets me started with Google Visualization API which i ll be using in my application for drawing charts with JSON data. Any suggestion.

**EDIT:**
I was going through this question [Iterating over json object for drawing a column chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529630/iterating-over-json-object-for-drawing-a-column-chart). This is what exactly i am trying to do? Any good ex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at Google's own page for the API? http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html It has a lot of very good examples demonstrating different features.

If that's not enough, try the Chart Wizard that allows you to interactively build your chart data and then just copy the source code: http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/ (for static image charts)

The navigation is a little confusing due to static vs. dynamic charts. Plus there are widgets, etc. But the examples and source code is there, so just look carefully around.

Comment: but google visualization charts seems to have a json data as datasource

Comment: You give Google your data and it gives you back the chart. That's what the example you pointed at does, AFAIK.

If you want something different, you may want to clarify your question by contrasting it to what you already see in Google documentation.

Are you saying that you have a JSON source and you are trying to transform it into format Google Viz uses as input for your chart. Then you need to choose which chart or at least which type of chart you need help with. The input formats are quite different.

Of course, that's what the other question did and got no replies.